# Solving recurrence sequence using an ODE

Tags: differential-equations, recursion

I'm trying to solve the recurrence

```
a[n] == 0 for n < l
a[l] == 1
a[n] == (l + 2(n - l) a[n - l] + (n - l)(n - 1) a[n - 1])/n(n - l + 1) for n >= l
```

using the ODE

```
l = 2;
DSolve[(x^2 y''[x] + (2 - l) x y[x]) (x - 1) + 2 x^(l + 1) y'[x] + (l x^l)/(1 - x) == 0, 
  y[x], x]
```

For `l = 2` it works, but not for `l > 2`. Is it possible to do it? Maybe there is another way to solve this recurrence ?

Comment: @m_goldberg The previous version was useful for experimenting with `RSolve[]`

Comment: Which is the real problem you need to solve: the recurrence or the ODE?

Comment: @bills I need to solve the recurrence.

Comment: You mean you want to get a analytic formula of `a[n]` for any `l`?

Comment: Could you please post the solution for `a[n]` for `l=2` ? I don't know how to link the second equation to the first.

Comment: The definition of your recurrence is ambiguous. Let's say we choose `n=l=4` and you call `a[n]`, then you certainly have to choose your second line `a[l]==1` because `n==l`. On the other hand, your third line tells us, that you have to use this when `n>=l` which contains `n==l` too. Can you clear this?

Comment: @xzczd Yes I need analytical solution

Comment: @b.gatessucks There is the way to find link between the recurrence and ODE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539078/generating-function-of-recurrence-sequence

Comment: @b.gatessucks I mostly need to find a[Infinity]. For this I need to solve ODE. For l=2 I have no expression for a[n], but I solve ODE and found a[Infinity]=1/E^2

Comment: @halirutan I don't see the ambiguity you mention. If `n==l` then using the third line I get `a[n] == 1` because all the `a[...]` terms are zero because of the first line and the rest nicely combine to give `1`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Then the second line is not necessary. I haven't looked at it very closely.

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков OK stupid question : in the equation for `a[n]`, is `(n-l+1)` in the numerator or in the denominator (like `n`) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a change of Variable

```
s[k_]:= s[k]= RSolve[{a[p + m] == ((1 + p) (m + 2 p a[p] + p (-1 + m + p) a[-1 + m + p]))/(m + p) /. 
                 m -> k,  Sequence @@ Array[a@# == 0 &, k - 1, 0]}, a, p]
```

Which give DifferenceRoot solutions. So:

```
Grid[Table[a[n] /. s[m][[1]], {n, 1, 5}, {m, 1, 5}]] /. C[1] -> 0
```

Gives the same table as in @ubpdqn's answer, except that for `l==1` you get the solution expressed as some combinations of Bessel functions:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @belisarius... compact...reassuring for me.

Comment: I think that's the best one can do (+1)

Answer (score 2):

This is not an analytic solution of the recurrence. I generate a table based on the recurrence relation (if I interpret it correctly). I have change `l` to `m` as difficult to discriminate from one. If the values are wrong I have obviously made an error but perhaps can motivate other approaches.

```
f[m_, n_, mat_] := 
 1/n(1 - m + n) (m + (-1 + n) (-m + n) mat[[m, -1 + n]] + 
    2 (-m + n) mat[[m, -m + n]])
g[n_] := Module[
  {sa, pos},
  sa = Normal@
    SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1, {i_, j_} /; i > j -> 0}, {n, n}, "x"];
  pos = Position[sa, "x"];
  Fold[ReplacePart[#1, #2 -> f[#2[[1]], #2[[2]], #1]] &, sa, pos]

  ]
```

Tabulating `g[5]`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you not satisfied with difference root objects? I think that @belisarius has given the most general solution. If you want to give your sequence values and see how it behaves there's no reason to use `RSolve`. You can define the n-th term recursively and build the sequence from the bottom up (in what follows, I changed `l` to `q`):

```
ClearAll[a, g, data, data2, plot, an6];
a[n_] := If[n >= q,
      ((1 + n - q) (q + (-1 + n) (n - q) a[-1 + n] + 2 (n - q) a[n - q]))/
      n,
      0]
```

Now you can generate a few terms and watch `a` grow:

```
data = Table[Table[{q, k, Log[a[k]]}, {q, 1, k}], {k, 1, 16}];
```

where I take the logarithm because it grows too fast and I want to plot it. Here's how (the logarithm of) your sequence looks for the first few `n`, `q`:

```
plot = ListPointPlot3D[Flatten[data, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you are after solutions for large `n` and small `q`s the following might be a bit quicker than @belisaruis's:

```
    g[q_] := b[n] /.
  RSolve[{b[n] == ((1 + n - q) (q + (-1 + n) (n - q) b[-1 + n] + 2 (n - q) b[n - q]))/n,
    b[q] == 1},
   b[n], n]
```

but for every `g[n]` it needs `n-1` additional values to determine an equal number of constants. So

```
g[1]
```

evaluates to

```
(*out*){(1/(n! (2 + n)!))
 2 (BesselI[2, 2] n! (2 + n)! - 
    HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {1 + n, 3 + n}, 1]) Pochhammer[
   1, -1 + n] Pochhammer[3, -1 + n]}
```

but

```
g[2]
```

evaluates to a difference root object with one constant. The point here is that you have another constant to determine for every increment of `q`. So I can use my `a[n]` above to determine the constants at every step:

```
data2 = Table[Table[a[k], {q, 1, k}], {k, 1, 17}];
```

which gives a table like the ones described in other answers. Now, say

```
an6 = First@With[{q = 6}, 
      g[q] /. Thread[
        C /@ Range[q - 1] -> data2[[q + 1 ;; 2 q - 1, q - 1]]]]
```

gives you a difference root object for `q=6` and any `n`$\geq$`q`. The last bit is a set of rules that replaces the constants based on the table of values `data2` above. This is exactly where the problem lies: the higher the `q` the more constants you need and my function `a[n]` gets quite slow for larger `n`, `q` so this essentially transposes the problem with speed to generating values to replace the constants. As I said, I don't think you can do anything more general than what @belisarius did. But if you care for the first few `q`s this might be more viable as you have a difference root object for any `n` given a `q` so in my example for `q=6` above, you can go to any `n`:

```
Show[ListPointPlot3D[Table[{6, n, Log[an6]}, {n, 1, 35}], 
  PlotStyle -> Red], plot, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `data2` you can do the same thing for `q` between 1 and 9 and this will definitely be fast the more `n` grows.